# This question should not have been closed.

Tags: discussion

I'm referring to this question: [How important is graceful degradation of JavaScript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/23535/5497)

No offense to moderator **bigown**, but I don't see how this is fair or constructive behavior.  The question has plenty of upvotes.  The answers have plenty of upvotes.  It has been viewed 1,305 times at the time of this writing, and there are 23 answers and plenty of comments and discussion!  The community obviously approves of this question.

However, bigown thinks the question doesn't meet the six guidelines.  He's entitled to an opinion.  According to the privileges page, [4 other people typically need to share his opinion to close the question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions).  I realize moderators can just close a question on their own, but this seems like overzealous behavior.

Comment: Which of the six guidelines do you think your question meets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Popularity is not an argument to keep a question open. Doesn't meet the 6 guidelines is an argument to close it. That were my opinion. If 5 users or other moderators disagree, it can be reopened. Other 5 users or other moderator could close it again.

You could defend your question here but you choose defend its popularity.

I learnt nothing with that question. I just see what other **people** do when they *surf*.

In fact I could close it again as Not A Real Question.

Comment: Alright.  I see your point.

Answer (score 8):

How exactly does this relate to programming? Anybody can surf with javascript disabled: doctors, lawyers, dentists.

The only constructive form of this I can think of is

"Should we program our site to require JavaScript?"

where the implied subtext is

"Show me data that indicates how many people don't have JavaScript enabled, so we can program our site with the correct strategy"

Answer (score 1):

Edit your question with Jeff's suggestions and I'll bet it'll get reopened.  The question is good, but too subtle.  It probably shouldn't be directed at "you" but at "your clients".

Here's the real criteria to getting your question through the content filter:

1. Is it about something that has to do with your job as a programmer besides code itself?
2. Are you not just ranting about something?
3. Does anyone need to know the answer to this question?
4. Did remember to fail to mention what country you're using as a frame of reference to asking this question?
5. Did you use the queen's english?
6. Is your question politically correct?

Comment: I took your advice and rephrased.

Comment: @Stephen good fix, I think the next step is flagging the question for moderator attention assuming he doesn't reverse his decision within the day.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with Programming.  Please reread the name of the site.

Comment: Agree but don't need to be rude.

Comment: @Renesis, I have no idea why you think this answer was rude.  It was straight to the point with no name calling.

Comment: "Please reread the name of the site" implies the user is too stupid to remember it.

Comment: @Renesis, NO, it implies that he hasn't paid enough attention to it.  I'm drawing his attention to it.

Comment: It ***was*** rude.  But I forgive you.